# Google reports are not shown in pdf report in Mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, google-visualization, pdf-generation

I'm using google charts in reports (https://developers.google.com/chart/)
and I'm generating Pdf files of these html files using the below code:

```
      public FileResult DownloadReport(string viewName, string fileName, MpReportType type, int id = 0, DateRangeType? dateRangeType = null)
        {
            const string CONTAINER = "#reportContainer";
            var model = GetModel(type, id, true, dateRangeType);
            return DownloadReportInternal(viewName, fileName, model, CONTAINER);
        }

      private FileResult DownloadReportInternal(string viewName, string fileName, ReportGeneratorModel model, string container = "#reportContainer")
        {
            var htmlToConvert = GetHtmlFromView(viewName, model);

            var hiddenElements = new string[] { ".reportHiddenElement" };


            var pdfStream = ConvertHtmlToPdf(htmlToConvert, container, hiddenElements);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

                int read;
                while ((read = pdfStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                var pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();

                FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
                fileResult.FileDownloadName = fileName;
                return fileResult;
            }
        }


      protected string RenderViewAsString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, null);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                new ViewDataDictionary(model),
                new TempDataDictionary(),
                stringWriter);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
```

I'm calling DownloadReport from Views.

this is part of View which contains chart section

```
 <div class="ring-chart__chart" id="cumulativeExpenseSummaryChart"></div>
```

and this is the function of calling the chart in js:

```
 var drawCharts = function() {
            @if (Model.ComprehensiveCashflowTrack.ExpensePieChart != null)
            {
                var chart = Model.ComprehensiveCashflowTrack.ExpensePieChart;
                <text>
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['@chart.Name', '@chart.Description']
                        @foreach (var item in chart.Items)
                        {
                            <text>, ['@item.Name', @item.Value]</text>
                        }
                    ]);
                    //DrawCashflowRingChart('Monthly Expense Summary', 'cumulativeExpenseSummaryChart', data);
            drawNetCashflowPieChart('Monthly Expense Summary', 'cumulativeExpenseSummaryChart', data);
                </text>
            }
        }
```

***Issue***: 
*the charts are not loaded in pdf reports.* they're shown correctly in the HTML page.

Comment: the charts are loaded and drawn asynchronously, you will need to wait until their `'ready'` event fires, before creating the pdf...

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks for the reply.. but I can see them in the html file created .doesn't it mean they're loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for some of the pdf's after I changed the way google visualization is loading .
instead of loading the charts in ***document.ready()*** , as this :

```
  google.charts.load('current',
      {
         callback: drawCharts,
         packages: ['corechart']
      });
```

I changed it to this :

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
```

It shouldnt consider as answer since its not successful in some of the pdf s.

Comment: `google.charts.load` will wait for the page to load by default, and can be used in place of `document.ready` -- although it still works, `google.load` from the `jsapi` library is old and should no longer be used, see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) for more info...